# setting up GLEW windows?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl, glew

I have visual studio 2010 and I want to set up glew.h on it.
i do this step but still I have linker error:
1.download glew pack

2.copy .h files to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include

3.copy .lib files to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib

4.copy glew32.dll to C:\Windows\SysWOW64

5.and finally go to myproject properties then go to linker->input add glew32.lib, 
glu32.lib, and opengl32.lib to Additional Dependencies

but I still have this error:

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewBlendEquation

Answer (score 3):

I've been confronted to the same issue today, so even if I'm one month late for the answer, just add GLEW_STATIC to your preprocessor's definitions.

Comment: My errors had been solved but when i run my program, it have runtime error! 
i use your solution but my errors return back again!!


thank you.

Comment: I use glewInit at first line of main .
glewInit returned an error and program finished.

Comment: The openGL context must be created before glewInit is called. First open you window with any utility library (GLFW, SDL, whatever) and then call glewInit.

Answer (score 2):

That's a common problem. Just download the source, recompile it and it will work.